# Bootstrap 4 in IE10, Rails application: grid classes broken for table columns

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-10

I'm using bootstrap 4.0.0 in a Rails 5.1.5 application.

I have this table:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr class="table-title-bg">
    <th class="col-1">COD SAP</th>
    <th class="col-4">DESCRIPCION</th>
    <th class="col-2">REF. FABRICANTE</th>
    <th class="col-1">FABRICANTE</th>
    <th class="col-1">STOCK</th>
    <th class="col-1">PRECIO MEDIO(€)</th>
    <th class= "col-2">PLANTA</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <% parts.each do |part| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= part.sap_cod %></td>
      <td><%= part.descripcion_maestro %></td>
      <td><%= part.ref_fabricante %></td>
      <td><%= part.fabricante %></td>
      <td><%= part.stock %></td>
      <td><%= part.precio_medio %></td>
      <td><%= part.planta_nombre %></td>
    </tr>
  <%end%>
</tbody>
```

The problem is that the first column, which is col-1, is actually taking like 8 columns of the layout in IE10:

[image: IE10]

This is working fine in Chrome as shown in the image. Also you can see how the grid from the form above is working fine in both cases (apart from the color problem in IE10)

[image: Same elements in Chrome]

Any suggestion about how to fix it?